# custom cursor with onclick sound effect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the cursor to a custom image with a sound effect.  My current problem is the cursor disappears but the replacement image does not show up, and the sound clip is not playing. What did I do wrong?

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv1 {
position:absolute;
width:1152px;
height:864px;
z-index:2;
left:25px;
top:25px;
}
</style>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function setCursor() {
oBoxInner.innerText=sInput.value;
oBoxInner.style.display='block';
oBox.style.cursor="crosshair.gif";
}
</SCRIPT>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function playSound(soundfile) {
document.getElementById("gunShot").innerHTML=document.getElementById("gunShot").innerHTML="<embed src=\""+gunshot.mp3+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
}
</script>   

</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000">

<div id="apDiv1">
<span id="gunShot" onclick="playSound('gunshot.mp3');">
<a href="3.html" onmouseover="setCursor" onmouseclick="playSound('gunshot.mp3')">    <img src="score.gif" width="1152" height="864" alt="yep" />
</a></span>
</div>

</body>
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

I'm using dreamweaver with both PC and Mac for multiple browser compatibility, mainly IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. I was thinking the .gif might be part of the issue instead of .cur. The other cursor code I'm using is this:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#test-area').mouseout(function(){
       $('#mycursor').hide();
       return false;
   });
   $('#test-area').mouseenter(function(){
       $('#mycursor').show();
       return false;
   });
    $('#test-area').mousemove(function(e){
        $('#mycursor').css('left', e.clientX - 20).css('top', e.clientY + 7);
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#test-area {
    height: 1152px;
    width:864px;
    border: 3px dashed #CCCCCC;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px; 
    cursor: none; 
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index:1;
}
#mycursor {
    cursor: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(crosshairs.cur); 
    repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">

  <div id="test-area">
        Move mouse over this area.
  </div>

  <div id="mycursor">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: where's `oBox` being defined from, and what browser(s) have you tested from

Comment: `oBoxInner` and `oBox` are not even defined. And WTH is `document.getElementById("gunShot").innerHTML=document.getElementById("gunShot").innerHTML`???

Comment: And you are using `bgcolor="#000000"`??? Stop those and start using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you have a few errors in the code

`oBox` is not defined.  `oBox.style.cursor="crosshair.gif";`

The cursor is best to be `.cur`

the `embed` tag i only think supports MIDI, and your referencing `gunshot.mp3` in your oncick and trying to call reffrence to `\""+gunshot.mp3+"\"` in the src, should be `soundfile`

and you have `document.getElementById("gunShot").innerHTML=document.getElementById("gunShot").innerHTML` TWICE?

What browsers are you wanting to support the sound? Netscape, IE6, Chrome.. ect